# NSERVICEBUS - Type was not registered in serializer

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I've followed the NServiceBus getting started guide to the letter, with the only change made was to add properties to my message class.

When I try to run it, I get:

```
Type [my type] was not registered in the serializer. 
Check that it appears in the list of configured assemblies/types to scan.
```

I have followed the guidance on http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/serialization/type-was-not-registered but this hasn't helped at all. After clearing the folders, doing a clean and rebuilding I still have the same problem, with the exception firing when the generated INServiceBusComponent class calls Bus.Send.

Anyone have any ideas for things I can try here?

Comment: Can you post the message class?  Are you marking it as an IMessage?

Comment: With NSB 3.x no longer need to use IMessage

Comment: dtyron - thanks dude - that seems to sort the problem out. The project generated by the Visual Studio Template didn't even have references to NServiceBus. Added references and IMessage and problem solved. Thank you :).

Comment: hugh - using NServiceBus 3.2 - and it doesn't work without IMessage.

Comment: You need to define a convention if you dont want to use IMessage. See NSB documentaion for unobtrusive mode

Comment: @blackspy: would you mind adding the adding of the IMessage as the solution so that we can close this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer provided by dtryon - adding IMessage fixed this.

```
[Serializable]
public class MyMessage : IMessage
{
}
```